# Configurando um valor option em um jQuery Multiselect dropdown

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3

Estou usando a biblioteca [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/):

```
$("select#final option[value='" + data[0].final + "']").prop('selected', true);
$('select#final').multiselect("refresh");
```

Como o código acima eu quero selecionar um determinado `option` do `select`. Sendo que não funciona. Se eu copiar o código e executar no console funciona.

Comment: Confira o guia [JS, CSS e HTML executáveis no corpo da pergunta ou resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4463/201)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vendo a documentação do plugin, ela já te fornece um [**método**](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods) `select` para te ajudar nessa tarefa:

```
$('seuSelect').multiselect('select', ['1', '2', '4']);
```

Segue o [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/7yq7fvsq/118/) que usei para teste :)